# Convert rows to columns in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

We have one table called *Licenses*. This is what it looks like:

| CustNum | LicenseAddress | License | ExpiryDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 155 | 123 | Y32CA | 12/31/2018 |
| 155 | 998 | Y32CB | 12/31/2020 |
| 155 | 568 | Y32CC | 12/31/2022 |

Here is what I want it to look like:

| LicAddr1 | Lic1 | ExpiryDate1 | LicAddr2 | Lic2 | ExpiryDate2 | LicAddr3 | Lic3 | ExpiryDate3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Y32CA | 12/31/2018 | 998 | Y32CB | 12/31/2020 | 568 | Y32CC | 12/31/2022 |

Here is the query I have currently, however it’s only returning NULLs:

```
SELECT LicAddr1, 
       Lic1,
       ExpiryDate1,
       LicAddr2,
       Lic2,
       ExpiryDate2,
       LicAddr3,
       Lic3,
       ExpiryDate3
FROM (SELECT CustNum, LicenseAddress, License, ExpiryDate FROM Licenses) d
PIVOT (
       MAX(ExpiryDate) 
       FOR CustNum IN (LicAddr1, Lic1, ExpiryDate1, LicAddr2, Lic2, ExpiryDate2, LicAddr3, Lic3, ExpiryDate3) 
      ) piv
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's not how `PIVOT` works. You've asked for columns that summarize `MAX(ExpiryDate)` for `CustNum` having the values `LicAddr1`, `Lic1`, `ExpiryDate1`... but `CustNum` only ever has the value `155`. This needs an entirely different approach. Are you sure you don't need the `CustNum` in your result, and are you sure there will never be more than 3 licenses? A variable number of licenses (dynamic pivot) is a different kind of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PIVOT` isn't really what you're after, especially since you're trying to get multiple values from each row (which doesn't work very well with the aggregation `PIVOT` tries to offer).

I'm assuming here you want the most recent three licenses, in which case we can apply a row number per `CustNum`, ordered by `ExpiryDate` (newest first), then flip them so they are left-to-right oldest-to-newest:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT CustNum, LicenseAddress, License, ExpiryDate,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustNum ORDER BY ExpiryDate DESC)
  FROM dbo.Licenses
)
SELECT CustNum,
  LicAddr1    = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN LicenseAddress END),
  Lic1        = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN License        END),
  ExpiryDate1 = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN ExpiryDate     END),
  LicAddr2    = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN LicenseAddress END),
  Lic2        = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN License        END),
  ExpiryDate2 = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN ExpiryDate     END),
  LicAddr3    = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN LicenseAddress END),
  Lic3        = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN License        END),
  ExpiryDate3 = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN ExpiryDate     END)
FROM cte
GROUP BY CustNum;
```

Results:

| CustNum | LicAddr1 | Lic1 | ExpiryDate1 | LicAddr2 | Lic2 | ExpiryDate2 | LicAddr3 | Lic3 | ExpiryDate3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 155 | 123 | Y32CA | 2018-12-31 | 998 | Y32CB | 2020-12-31 | 568 | Y32CC | 2022-12-31 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=f6cec53e826b2518a8a75cf8fea8bb84)